# How does the C# compiler decide to emit retargetable assembly references?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, portable-class-library

Retargetable assembly references have been introduced for the .NET Compact Framework and are now used to support Portable Class Libraries.

Basically, the compiler emits the following MSIL:

```
.assembly extern retargetable mscorlib
{
    .publickeytoken = (7C EC 85 D7 BE A7 79 8E )                         
    .ver 2:0:5:0
}
```

How does the C# compiler understand it has to emit a retargetable reference, and how to force the C# compiler to emit such reference even outside of a portable class library?

Comment: No hints from MSBuild target files? I wonder what you need to pass to the compiler from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the assembly itself, it's an assembly flag, ie [assembly: AssemblyFlags(AssemblyNameFlags.Retargetable)].

Make note that this flag is meaningless outside of platform assemblies - custom assemblies cannot be retargetable.

For references, it's copied as part of the name from the assembly being referenced.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. I was hoping to get rid of the message `Could not load file or assembly 'PostSharp, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=53d2effcf2ee70dc, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)` when providing (through IHostAssemblyStore) another assembly than what the CLR requested, but I still get the error even with a retargetable reference. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Retargable won't let you key jump a user assembly, like I'm assuming you are attempting. It is entirely for CLR internal purposes. I'm not an expert on the hosting APIs, but I think LoadFile might allow you to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try another solution: same short name, same strong-name key, but different version number. Normal binding policies should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help, but the following file was auto-generated and included in the build.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
[assembly: global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute(
   ".NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile4", 
   FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Portable Subset")]
```

This might hint to the compiler to do some magic.

Edit:

I think above makes a library portable. From the command line I can see `/nostdlib+` is used, and a portable `mscorlib.dll` is referenced (which I assume has the same attribute as mentioned above).

"...\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile4\mscorlib.dll"

Comment: The `TargetFrameworkAttribute` is also present for Client and Full Framework builds for v4, it isn't around for v3.5. This might be why they added the attribute. As of v4, it also offers a very easy way to determine if an assembly was built for the full framework or the client profile.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Thanks, and I guess it is obsolete now given the client profile is gone in 4.5? ;p

Comment: Even in .NET 4 the difference between the client profile and full download was a couple of MB lol, not worth it - probably why they canned it in favour of PCL.

Comment: Thanks. The reference to the portable mscorlib.dll may be the point.

Comment: The TargetFrameworkAttribute is actually meaningless when it comes to portability. Old style portable (ie mscorlib-based), it is based on the retargetable reference to mscorlib. New style portable (ie System.Runtime-based) it soley based on the fact that System.Runtime, et al are present at runtime.

Comment: We discuss this at depth over here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/NET-45-David-Kean-and-Marcea-Trofin-Portable-Libraries.

Comment: @DavidKean: Thanks, going to check that out now :)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed by experimenting that the C# compiler would make an reference compiler as retargetable if the referenced assembly is marked as retargetable (a modifier on the `.assembly` section in MSIL). I did not find how the compiler decides to make the assembly retargetable, yet.